# How store data from a form into an exam table that contains foreign keys in laravel 5?

Tags: forms, laravel-5, php-5.6

Hi I'm trying to store some data from a form to an exam table where I have three foreign keys , I get those foreign keys from a select input like this `{!! Form::open(['route' => 'exam.store','files'=>true]) !!}`

```
<div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('session','Session :') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" name="session">
       @foreach ($sessions as  $session)
           <option value='{{$session->idsess}}'>{{$session->libellesess}} </option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('prof','Enseignant :') !!}
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="iden">
        @foreach ($users as   $user)
            <option value='{{ $user->getIdattribute()}}'>{{$user->getFullNameAttribute()}} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">

{!! Form::label('date','Date:') !!}
    </div>
<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::date('date',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('heuredeb','Heure Début :') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('heuredeb',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'heure:minute']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('heurefin','Heure Fin :') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('heurefin',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'heure:minute']) !!}
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('matiere','Matiere :') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="matiere">
        @foreach ($matieres as  $matiere)
            <option value='{{$matiere->idmat}}'>{{$matiere->libellemat}} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('statut','Statut :') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::text('statut',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'statut']) !!}`
</div>

{!! Form::submit('Ajouter',['class'=>'col-md-12 btn btn-danger'])!!}`
{!! Form::close() !!}`
```

but I got  the following error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('gesup'.'gs_exam',
>   CONSTRAINT 'gs_exam_idsess_foreign' FOREIGN KEY ('idsess') REFERENCES
>   'gs_session' ('idsess') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL:
>   insert into 'gs_exam' () values ())

Comment: It gave you that error because, in your sql query `SQL: insert into gs_exam() values ())` there are no columns passed and also there are no values that can be inserted.

Comment: no I am talking about how can i insert data into a table that contains foreign keys wich I have in my form

Comment: It can be inserted through the `Eloquent Model` or using the `Query Builder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few strange things in your code.

If you have a `getIdattribute()` function in your model, change its name to `getIdAttribute()` (capital A) for convention and then you can access that attribute simply with `$user->id`. Same with `$user->getFullNameAttribute()`, just use `$user->fullName`. This is called an accessor: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Also, if you need help with your code, we are gonna need to see more. You did not show your controller function that is being called (store), how you are constructing your model neither how you're saving it.

Anyway, it should be really easy to assign a foreign key, it's just like a regular attribute:

```
function yourControllerMethod(Request $request)
{
   $model = new MyModel();
   //assuming matiere_id is the foreign key to the Matiere table
   $model->matiere_id = $request->get('matiere');
   ... more stuff
   $model->save();
}
```

You can also use the `associate` method to link it to a model you have.

How to set up relationships between models:
  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships
 How to save relationships:
   http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models